# What does "orthogonalize" mean?

Tags: terminology, linear-algebra, partial-least-squares

I have read in *The Elements of Statistical Learning* book and particularly in the Partial Least Squares (PLS) section:

> Orthogonalize each $x_j^{(m−1)}$ with respect to $z_m$.

I would like to know what "orthogonalize" means in this statement or general.

1- what orthogonal means?
 2- how to orthogonalise?

Comment: Could you expand your question by including the book's definitions for $x_j$ and $z_m$?

Comment: "Orthogonalize" most commonly refers to something along the lines of the [Gram-Scmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) (computationally, some variant of [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) would typically be used).

Comment: Two vectors are orthogonal if their dot product is zero.

Comment: Can you edit your question to specify whether you want to know (a) how to orthogonalise (b) what orthogonal means (c) why in this application the author(s) want to orthogonalise?

Answer (score 6):

I believe the quote refers to [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=yPfZBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=elements%20of%20statistical%20learning%20partial%20least%20squares&source=bl&ots=RXt_BdXAWs&sig=5ICnQSiF8DqVk7HeLbdgU8zvIyU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZypDZ79POAhWGMSYKHZYVAr8Q6AEIMTAD#v=onepage&q=elements%20of%20statistical%20learning%20partial%20least%20squares&f=false) algorithm, where the relevant line reads:

$x_j^m=x_j^{m-1}-\frac{\langle z_m,x_j^{m-1}\rangle}{\langle z_m,z_m\rangle}z_m$

Here the authors are using the angle-brackets to denote an [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition), which is essentially the standard vector dot product from Physics 101.

The second term is the [orthogonal projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) of $x_j^{m-1}$ onto $z_m$. By subtracting this from $x_j^{m-1}$, the result $x_j^m$ is made *orthogonal* to $z_m$.

Comment: +1 Often in statistics this operation would be called "taking the residual of $x^{(m-1)}$ in the regression against $z$."

Comment: @ whuber you mean the orthogonal operation